# ¿Cómo asignar fechas entre dos rangos?

Tags: javascript, json, array, jsonobject

Buen día amigos,

tengo la siguiente duda, resulta que tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos:

```
var array1 = [
          {'fecha':'6:00',
           'datos'  1
          }, 
          {'fecha':'7:00'
           'datos' 2
          }, 
          {'fecha':'9:00'
           'datos': 3
          }
       ];
```

Como pudieron notar falta la fecha con el valor '8:00' es decir la consegutiva, ¿hay manera de agregar a ese arrreglo los que falten en ese rango? (en este caso el rango es '6:00' hasta '9:00') en este ejemplo falta '8:00' la idea es agregar los faltantes en cierto rango, algo así

```
var array1 = [
          {'fecha':'6:00',
           'datos'  1
          }, 
          {'fecha':'7:00'
           'datos' 2
          }, 
           {'fecha':'8:00'
           'datos' 0
          }, 
          {'fecha':'9:00'
           'datos': 3
          }
       ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una función como ésta completa las horas faltantes. Cabe aclarar que no las ordena, tocaría ordenar después el array por las fechas del objeto.

La lógica es que extrae el array de fechas, después busca sobre ese array las faltantes (de acuerdo al rango). Finalmente agrega las faltantes al array inicial (se modifica el array de entrada).

```
function completaFechas(array, fechaMin, fechaMax) {
/* Aqui se define el minimo y maximo del rango */
var min = parseInt(fechaMin.split(':')[0]);
var max = parseInt(fechaMax.split(':')[0]);

/* Se crea array solo con las fechas y se detecta el consecutivo para el valor de 'datos' */
var arrayFechas = [];
var id = 0;

array.forEach(function (obj) {
  arrayFechas.push(obj.fecha)
  if (obj.datos > id) {
    id = obj.datos;
  }
});

/* Se detectan las fechas faltantes de acuerdo al objeto */
var faltantes = [];
for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {

  var fecha = i + ':00';
  if (!arrayFechas.includes(fecha)) {
    id += 1;
    var objFalta = { // Objeto personalizado
      'fecha': fecha,
      'datos': id
    };
    faltantes.push(objFalta);
  }
}

/* Se agrega al array inicial los faltantes */
array.push(...faltantes);
}
```

Se utiliza de la siguiente forma, definiendo las fechas del rango:

```
completaFechas(array1, '6:00', '9:00');
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Mil gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba. ¿También hay una manera de que sea con formato de fecha  dia-mes? Tendría que cambiar el valor de fecha que está dentro del for?

Comment: Exacto, tocaría cambiar como se calcula la fecha en el `for` y como se detecta el mínimo y el máximo al inicio de la función.

Comment: He intendado, pero aún no logro conseguirlo ya que concateno el mes pero esa no es la idea

Comment: Como sería el formato de la fecha? `HH:mm dd-mm`? Y la idea sería completar todas las horas en un rango verdad?

Comment: Sí, aunque por ahora solo necesito dd-mm

Answer (score 0):

La función para agregar objetos a un array es "Push()":
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

En tu caso deberias crear el objeto a agregar:

```
var objeto = {'fecha':'8:00'
              'datos': 0 }
```

Y luego simplemente insertarlo a traves de la linea:

```
array1.push(objeto)
```

Vale aclarar que puedes agregar varios objetos separados por coma.

Comment: Esa solución no me sirve porque me tocaría meter los datos manualmente, lo que necesito una funcion entre el rango y que retorne los faltantes y luego ahí agregarselos, ¿me entiendes? porque imagínate si el rango es más largo, me tocaría ver cuáles faltan y luego meternos manualmente

Comment: Si, entiendo. En ese caso deberias recorrer el vector obteniendo los elementos bajo el indice "fecha". Creas una función para descubrir los faltantes y automaticamente los agregas bajo la funcion que te pase en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue recorrer el primer array y evaluar cual hora falta para luego crearla y luego crear un nuevo array con las horas completas:

```js
var array1 = [
  {'fecha' : '6:00',
   'datos' :  1
  }, 
  {'fecha' : '7:00',
   'datos' : 2
  }, 
  {'fecha' : '10:00',
   'datos' : 3
  }
];

let fechaAnterior = array1[0].fecha.split(":")
var horaAnterior = parseInt(fechaAnterior[0]);
var array2 = [];
var datos = 1;

array1.forEach((elemento,indice) => {

  let fecha = elemento.fecha.split(":");
  let hora = parseInt(fecha[0]);
  var horasFaltantes = (hora - horaAnterior);
  
  for(var i = horasFaltantes; i > 1; i--){
    var nuevaHora = (hora - i) + 1;
    array2.push({"fecha": nuevaHora+":00","datos":datos});
    datos++;
  }
  
  array2.push({"fecha": hora+":00","datos":datos});
  
  datos++;
  horaAnterior = hora;
  
});

console.log(array2);
```